# Recommendations for modelling panel data

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, linear-regression

sending positive wishes to y'all. I have about 10 years of growth rates in real estate prices and some other macroeconomic variables such as inflation, unemployment rates, fuel prices, growth in prices of raw materials among many others. I want to analyze the causality of all of these variables on the growth in real estate prices. The simplest thing would be to build a linear regression model, but given this is not cross-sectional and more like a time series data, I'm a little confused. Could you help me understand what should be the right statistical approach here to determine the drivers of real estate growth?

Comment: Hi. The variables you're mentioning look indeed as time series. But your title says panel data. Could you please clarify? And if you have many cross sectional groups, how specific are they?

Comment: That was an error. Please ignore, it'll simply be time series data. Will OLS suffice?

Comment: Great! If all of them are stationary and you comply to OLS assumptions, you're good to go. If not, you have many alternatives. Perhaps this link can help: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-complete-guide-to-time-series-analysis-and-forecasting-70d476bfe775

Comment: Thank you! Just wanted to confirm the same